# put me in a few job search workshops (for) next week

Tags: sentence-structure

Two days ago, my employment counselor spoke with me about my job search. I told him that I needed some help with my cover letter and resume. I also said that I would like to know more about the current job market. After our meeting, I saw my friend in a shopping center. I spoke English to him because he didn't understand my native language. This is what I said to him.

(ex) My friend asked me, "Where did go you?"

I replied, "I went to see my employment counselor and asked him to help me with my cover letter and resume."

He asked, "How did your meeting go?"

I said, "He put me in a few job search workshops (for) next week."

---

My example tells a true story about my job search. I use the past tense of "to put" in my last response because my employment counselor already put me in the workshops which will take place next week.

I would like to ask a question.

Do I need the word "for" in my last response?

Comment: Considering that this is a casual, informal conversation, "for" would add clarification, but it's not necessary. Your friend probably understood what you had meant. And excellent post. Very detailed, including the set-up.

Answer (score 1):

No, "for" is not necessary.

> I am saving this sandwich to eat next week.
>   I am saving this sandwich to eat for next week.

are both equivalent especially since the reference to "next week" is unambiguous to what it refers to.

Comment: Here there is another verb offered (to eat) later in the sentence that we are modifying, but if we left just the noun (sandwich) as did the OP, then it doesn't work:  "I am saving this sandwich next week."  Now we are modifying the verb "saving" instead of the noun "sandwich", which changes the sentence's meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.  To be "correct", you do need the word "**for**" to indicate that "next week" is not modifying the only verb in the sentence, "put" (past tense). This sentence feels doubly strange due to using past tense for something done next week.

However, as mentioned in another answer, it is common to "cut corners" in casual speech if it makes things easier to say without confusing the meaning too much.